# What would humans look like on a tidally locked moon with 0.7 G, 0.85 atm of pressure and at the distance similar to mars? (more info in the picture)

Tags: science-based, planets, humans

In the picture is the info box of the tidally locked moon of Vaskas. I'm working on a nation what lives on this moon but I would like to know how people on this moon would look like. (This is my first time posting on this website). The picture has all the information known about this moon. The moon has about 70% gravity, 85% the air pressure, the oxygen level is slightly higher and the moon is tidally locked to gas giant. The moon is about 1.5 AU away from the star and it receives tidal heating.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please read our [help] to understand what we expect from good questions. Also, please put relevant information in text. Not everybody can read pictures.

Comment: This is my first post on this website :D

Comment: Given the vast diversity in how humans look on Earth, what makes you think that there would be a singular answer to this question on another habitable planet?

Comment: *Come, listen, my men, while I tell you again the five unmistakable marks by which you may know, wheresoever you go, the warranted genuine Snarks. Let us take them in order. The first is the taste, which is meagre and hollow, but crisp: like a coat that is rather too tight in the waist, with a flavour of Will-o’-the-wisp. [...] It next will be right to describe each particular batch: distinguishing those that have feathers, and bite, and those that have whiskers, and scratch.* (Lewis Carroll, *The Hunting of the Snark*, 1876.)

Comment: @sphennings I'm more looking for answer, They would taller/shorter. Their bones would be thicker/thinner. They would have more/less hemoglobin in their blood. The skin color would be darker/lighter. Their muscles would be weaker/stronger. Kinda like that.

Comment: @Sanderv22v  I presume that by "gravity" you means surface gravity, which means that you neglected to give the escape velocity of your moon.  According to this surface gravity calculator  https://philip-p-ide.uk/doku.php/blog/articles/software/surface_gravity_calc it should be 0.69 g and c according to this escape velocity calculator https://www.calctool.org/astrophysics/escape-velocity  the escape velocity should be 7.815kilometers per second.  If your moon has 0.343 the mass of Earth.  But the astronomical symbol you use ndicates the moon has 0.343 the mass of the Sun.

Comment: @Sanderv22v The title asks about humans on the moon Vaskas, but the question asks about people living there.  Humans would look like some variety of Earth humans, while people could be members of a totally different species than Homo sapiens, and could lppk like any reasonably plausible science fiction aliens living on Earthlike planets.

Comment: @M.A.Golding The symbols are indeed not correct but the wiki I'm working is very complicated for me so I keep it like this until I find a way have the symbol for Earth Mass. Another team member got this data from Universe Engine. But the mass is 0.343 Earth masses. Do you know how this data would make humans different? I assume something would be change if they are stuck there for about 10.000 years. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sanderv22v Can you edit your post to ask one of those more specific questions?

Comment: (a) You have not told us how long the humans had been on the moon - that's a critical number as it takes eons for creatures to evolve substantially, (b) humans today come in a vast variety of shapes and sizes. Whether or not there would be a significant difference after any amount of time is dubious because it's the *average* that would shift. It's not unreasonable to answer this question, "they wouldn't really change at all" because the shift in average keeps humanity within the statistical norm for Earth.

Answer (score 2):

- Humans would obviously look taller on this planet, due to reduced gravity.
- 0.85 atm isn't much of a dealbreaker for humans. In fact, humans can live at air pressures of just 0.4 atm (air pressure at an altitude of 26,000 ft), beyond which humans can no longer acclimate.
- Since you only said "slightly" higher oxygen levels, I am going to assume the O<sub>2</sub> is around 22%. Using Omni calculator, this gives us an partial pressure of 189.48 millibars. In contrast, in Earth's atmosphere, oxygen exerts a partial pressure of 213.316 millibars.
- This means that humans will have slightly larger lungs, in order to get more oxygen. Large isn't the only change in the bodies. Their blood might contain more haemoglobin to absorb oxygen efficiently, and the humans might possess more efficient alveoli for better usage of oxygen.
- Since Vaskas is about as far as Mars from its Sun, this means that humans will evolve to have thicker skin and a fat layer to retain heat.
- Vaskas's rotational period lasts about 93 hours, nearly 4x as much as an Earth Day. This means that due to the increased nighttime period, humans will evolve larger pupils to allow more light, and certain night-vision features like tapetum lucidum, meaning that humans will have glowing eyes due to the tapetum lucidum's reflectivity.

In short, slightly larger chests, more height, glowing eyes and a thick skin might be the features of your average Vaskasian human.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir!

Comment: @Sanderv22v You are welcome =)

Comment: With such a small difference in oxygen partial pressure, I would expect that the organism would compensate by having a little more red blood cells rather that increasing lung capacity. After all, this is what the human organism actually does at moderate altitude.

Comment: If their species developed on Vaskas, they might have a fat layer for warmth and larger pupils. But if they migrated there from Earth (or some other warmer planet) after developing spacefaring tech, they have probably been able to keep their houses warm and lit, and have no evolutionary pressure to adapt to cold and dark. Earth humans living on high latitudes aren't generally fatter or larger-eyed than those in the tropics.